# Picasso: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, picasso

I'm using ViewPager to show welcome, register, and some other screens. those screens are fragments controlled by FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
private static class TourPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public TourPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            WellcomeTourFragment ta = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ta = WellcomeTourFragment.newInstance(R.layout.welcome_fragment);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ta = WellcomeTourFragment.newInstance(R.layout.signup_fragment);
                    break;
```

first fragment (WellcomeFragment) shows some views and background image loaded from internet using picasso library:

```
private ImageView bkgImage;

    public static WellcomeTourFragment newInstance(int layoutId){
            WellcomeTourFragment pane = new WellcomeTourFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(LAYOUT_ID, layoutId);
            pane.setArguments(args);
            return pane;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(getArguments().getInt(LAYOUT_ID, -1), container, false);
            this.bkgImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgView_Background);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(IMG_uRL)
                   .into(this.bkgImage);
        }
```

My problem here is that, i am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

I am sure the ImageView does exits in my welcome_fragment layout. but really don't know what makes target to be null.

Comment: Please include your welcome_fragment layout

Comment: Are you sure `rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgView_Background)` does not return `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the correct layout is being inflated?  Try debugging and looking at the rootView after it has been inflated.  Is it possible you are including the wrong layout id when you call your newInstance method?